# Vector subscript out of range from a vector of vectors

Tags: c++

Perhaps it is late but I am not seeing why I am getting a vector subscript out of range for this code:

```
int m = 3;
int n = 2;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> path(m, std::vector<int>(n, 0));
for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); ++i)
    path[0][i] = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < path[0].size(); ++i)
    path[i][0] = 1;
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using the indices correctly.

```
for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); ++i)
    path[0][i] = 1;
```

needs to be

```
for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); ++i)
    path[i][0] = 1; // Swap i and 0
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i < path[0].size(); ++i)
    path[i][0] = 1;
```

needs to be

```
for (int i = 0; i < path[0].size(); ++i)
    path[0][i] = 1; // Swap i and 0
```

Comment: I see, I thought that the first loop was putting a 1 for each entry in the row?

Comment: @Wolfy, the first block puts 1 in the first column of each row. The second block puts 1 in each column of the first row. I am not sure what you were trying to do.

Comment: I am following the maths notation of matrix i.e. the first row of a 3 (row) * 2 (col) matrix is a_00 a_01 a_02 thus I thought my first for loop made a_00 = 1 a_01 = 1 and a_02 = 1. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think I see it now, sorry

Comment: @Wolfy, Yes it does. The error was that you were using `i < path.size()` instead of `i < path[0].size()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you refine you code like that, the problem become very clearly.

```
int m = 3;
int n = 2;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> path(m, std::vector<int>(n, 0));
for (auto& subVec : path) {
    subVec[0] = 1;
}
std::vector<int>& firstVec = path[0];
for (auto& item : firstVec) {
    item = 1;
}
```

Comment: This really should be the accepted answer, as range-based for loops should be preferred over index-based ones.

Answer (score 1):

Try this change, I reversed your loop conditions.

```
int m = 3;
int n = 2;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> path(m, std::vector<int>(n, 0));
for (int i = 0; i < path[0].size(); ++i)
    path[0][i] = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); ++i)
    path[i][0] = 1;
```